# Remove duplicate cells from column B on column A

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns A and B.
column A (943 rows) has a list of numbers.
column B (356 rows) has a list of numbers taken from column A.

I need to cross reference the two columns and remove the numbers that appear in column B from column A. I should end up with 587 items, but using conditional formatting equation

=COUNTIF($A$1:$B$1000,A1)>1

it only removes about 70/100 items.

is there a better/faster/easier way to do this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
=Filter(A:A,CountIF(B:B,A:A)=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "delete". I'm guessing that this is done by conditional formatting.

Use this custom formula:
`=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$356, $A1)>0`

When designing your conditional formatting rule:

- the range is ONLY column A (A1:A943)
- the custom formula references ONLY Column B, and in absolute terms
- the custom formula references the entire data range in Column B ($B$1:$B$356)

---

**Sample**

[image: sample data]